# What is the benefit of using multiple steps to complete an if test?

Tags: php

What is the benefit of using multiple steps to test variables:

```
$VarLength = strlen($message);
if ($VarLength > 10)
    echo "Over Ten";
```

...versus just pushing the whole process into one if statement:

```
if ( strlen($message) > 10 )
    echo "Over Ten";
```

I'm wondering if the benefits go beyond code style, and the ability to re-use the results of the (in the example above) `strlen` result.

Comment: If $VarLength exists only for that one test then the second example is what you should use. Otherwise if $VarLength is going to be reused, then it makes sense to separate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the result of a function will be used multiple times, **it should be cached in a variable so as to obviate the need to waste resources to re-calculate its result**.

If the function result won't be re-used, it can simply be a matter of code readability to clearly delineate what's happening by storing the function return value in a variable before using it in an `if` condition.

Also, in terms of readability, you should always use curly braces even when not mandated by PHP syntax rules as @AlexHowansky mentions.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not really possible to answer technically, so this is more a comment than an answer.

Benefits beyond code-style and re-use of the result is when you change the code.

You might want to replace the `strlen()` function with some other function but you don't want to edit the line with the `if` clause while you do so. E.g. to prevent errors or side-effects. That *could* be a benefit, however it depends on code-style somehow. So as you exclude coding style from your question, it makes it hard to answer as that domain touches a lot how you can/should/would/want/must write code.

Comment: That's a good point, about the possibility of needing to change `strlen()` at some point & it not being a best practice to tinker with the `if` statement itself.

Comment: Another one is debugging. If you for some reason need to `var_dump` the length of the message (or want to [`assert`](http://php.net/assert) it), having the working code in it's own lines is useful, too. Additionally you should not fear variables, they help to make code better and they are normally very cheap, so feel encouraged to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Most of it is in the code style.  In terms of rapidity of the results, it doesn't change much.  If you are using $varLenght more then once, then you are saving the call to the function to obtain the length.  But even that, the time difference is extremely minimal (I would even like to say unnoticable).

But: When developping any applications, you have to keep in mind that you might not be the only one making changes to it down the road, or you might not be as fresh and up to date with the exact program you are writing.  Therefore, the cleaner the code, the easier it is in terms of maintenance, and THAT'S where you save a lot of time down the road.

Answer (score 1):

Best Practice dictates that functions be called minimally.  In your case the practice doesn't violate the rule, but it is not uncommon to find code like:

```
if ( strlen($message) > 100 )
    echo "Over Ten";
else if ( strlen($message) > 20 )
    echo "Over Ten";
else if ( strlen($message) > 10 )
    echo "Over Ten";
...
```

A common prevention is to always assign function results to a variable for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say there is any benefit apart from the re-use case you've already mentioned. Your latter case is more readable, probably faster, and probably less memory-intensive. I *would* however strongly recommend always using braces, even when your conditional is only one line:

```
if (condition) {
    statement;
}
```

Comment: Why the recommendation to use bracket on single line conditionals?

Comment: It is less error-prone. Many coding standards (e.g., Zend, Symfony, CodeIgniter) require them.